# Regex for [title](http://) links

Tags: php, regex, hyperlink

I'm trying to parse links using php with a structure such as `[google](http://google.com)`, and so far I've got this:

```
"/\[(.+?)\]((.+?\))/is"
```

The only part I can't get to work is the part with the parenthesis ')'.

Any help would be great!

[edit]

@jari - This is part of the code:

```
$find = array(
    "@\n@", 
    "/[**](.+?)[**]/is",
    "/\[(.+?)\]\((.+?)\)/is"
    );

$replace = array(
    "<br />",
    "<strong>$1</strong>",
    "<a href\"$1\" target=\"_blank\" rel=\"no follow\"></a>"
    );

$body = htmlspecialchars($body); 
$body = preg_replace($find, $replace, $body); 
return $body;
```

Comment: Specify a problem: what do you input and what do you desire to get?

Comment: You're missing one backslash on the opening `(`. But move the escaping to the outer pair rather than the inner.... `\((.+?)\)`

Comment: This is a stricter regex: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14599071/how-can-i-write-a-javascript-regular-expression-to-replace-hyperlinks-in-this-fo/14604030#14604030

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The parenthesis is a special character and usually marks **sub-patterns** inside your expression, so you need to escape them (just as you did with the square brackets, btw):

```
"/\[(.+?)\]\((.+?)\)/is"
```

Answer (score 0):

It should look something like:

```
\[([^\]]+)]\([^)]+\)
```

We are using `[^x]` which means, match anything that is not `x`.
 We have used this to capture in group one everything after the `[` which is not a `]`.
Same for the second group using `[^)]+`. Anything that is not a `)`.